# Joining multiple SELECT statements

Tags: mysql

I want to pull some data from MySQL table, this is the structure of the table (it's coming from 3rd party resource and I can't change it):

[image]

I want to get the sum of columns 1razredi, 2razredi... for range with yellow background (wdt_ID from 1 to 5) and from range with green background (wdt_ID from 13 to 17).
Like this:

[image]

I have managed to put together 5 separate queries, which give me 5 separate results for a single `nainhoje`, example for first `nainhoje` called PEŠ (wtd_ID = 1):

```
SELECT `PomladPes`.`nainhoje` AS `Način hoje`, `PomladPes`.`Pomlad` AS `Pomlad 2023`, `JesenPes`.`Jesen` AS `Jesen 2023` FROM
(SELECT 
    `nainhoje`, 
    SUM(case when `wdt_ID` = 1 then (`1razredi` + `2razredi` + `3razredi` + `4razredi` + `5razredi` + `6razredi` + `7razredi` + `8razredi` + `9razredi`) else 0 end ) as `Pomlad` 
    FROM `avs_wpdatatable_2` 
    WHERE `wdt_ID` = 1) AS `PomladPes`
JOIN 
(SELECT 
    `nainhoje`, 
    SUM(case when `wdt_ID` = 13 then (`1razredi` + `2razredi` + `3razredi` + `4razredi` + `5razredi` + `6razredi` + `7razredi` + `8razredi` + `9razredi`) else 0 end ) as `Jesen` 
    FROM `avs_wpdatatable_2` 
    WHERE `wdt_ID` = 13) AS `JesenPes`
ON `PomladPes`.`nainhoje` = `JesenPes`.`nainhoje`;
```

It returns

```
    Način hoje  Pomlad 2023     Jesen 2023
    PEŠ         36              44
```

I have 4 more queries for other `nacinhoje` : `SKIRO, ROLKA, ROLERJI`, `KOLO`, `AVTO` and  `ŠOLSKI AVTOBUS/JPP`

My question is, how could I join these 5 queries to get a result like in the second (smaller) image? That is sum of values for each `nainhoje` for wtd_ID 1 to 5 (called Pomlad 2023 in the second image) and for wtd_ID 14 to 17 (called Jesen 2023 in the second image).

Could it be done using different approach?

Since I've been warned about the focus and clarity of my SO questions, I hope I was clear enough this time. With my limited knowledge of SQL it's sometimes hard to ask a properly formulated question or on the other side find already answered similar questions.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just as a tip, if you're able to rewrite the example data to be in English then it will help others looking at your question - I know theoretically language doesn't matter in this context but it's easier to visualise if in English. Also I think uploading images in this case is valid.

Comment: Did you try `UNION`? Also, you must submit your DB Table DDL and data in an editable manner so the people can copy paste and render correct and quick advise.

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT nainhoje,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN wdt_ID BETWEEN 1 AND 5
                THEN (`1razredi` + `2razredi` + `3razredi` + `4razredi` + `5razredi` + `6razredi` + `7razredi` + `8razredi` + `9razredi`)
        END
    ) AS `Pomlad`,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN wdt_ID BETWEEN 13 AND 17
                THEN (`1razredi` + `2razredi` + `3razredi` + `4razredi` + `5razredi` + `6razredi` + `7razredi` + `8razredi` + `9razredi`)
        END
    ) AS `Jesen`
FROM avs_wpdatatable_2
WHERE wdt_ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
GROUP BY nainhoje;
```

The `WHERE` clause is not really necessary if the dataset is as small as your example.

Comment: This worked!

I had to make some minor changes: FROM should use table name, I also had to add WHERE wdt_ID NOT IN (6,12,18) after that since there are empty rows in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer. I totally missed the table name ‍♂️. The `WHERE` clause is not really necessary with such a small dataset, as the conditional aggregates only include the rows they are interested in.